# How to use touchAndHold event for sprite kit xcode 5

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a game with sprite kit and i need the character to move. I want the user to hold down the button for the character to move straight on the x axis. Right now you have to tap it multiple times for him to move.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting a x direction velocity on the touchBegan event and on the touchUp event set the velocity to 0.

1. Touch down on a Node (left or right)
2. Check if direction node was touched
3. Set speed based on which node was touched (+ value moves right, - value moves left)
4. When Touch is released, reset velocity of character to 0

Here is some code I stripped from my game for you:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];

CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];



if([self.moveRightNode containsPoint: location]) {
     NSInteger xSpeed = yourSpeed;
     character.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(yourspeed, 0);
}
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
character.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
```

}

When setting the physicsworld up, make gravity 0 or make the character.physicsworld.dynamic=NO.

Comment: It is just a skspritenode that I assume you use as a button (ex. moveLeftSpriteNode). There are no real buttons in spritekit so creating SKSpriteNodes to replicate these buttons works well. All you have to do is check on a touch if you have touched the SKSpriteNode and, if you did, execute some code. All of this is above except the creation and positioning of the SKSpriteNodes(for movement). I also only included move right because move left is the same except for making xspeed negative.

Comment: This is what I guess you write, but it gives me an error saying that "Property 'lArrow' not found on object of type 'MyScene *'; did you mean to access instance variable'lArrow'?"

Comment: Code: 'if([self.lArrow containsPoint: location1]) {
        NSInteger xSpeed = 5;
        charPos = charPos + 2;
        character.position = CGPointMake(charPos, charPos1);
        character.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(xSpeed, 15);
    }
}' @meisenman

Comment: I got rid of the comment. But now I figured out that it has to be a specific spot the location of where you touch. Which most of the time it wont execute the code. I need it so that when you hold down the button the guy keeps moving right/left. And when you release he will stop moving. I guess the code you gave me doesn't work. Or maybe I am just doing something wrong. I'll post code in next comment.

Comment: - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    
    location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    
    trans.position = location;
    
    if([lArrow containsPoint: location1]) {
        NSInteger xSpeed = 5;
        charPos = charPos + 2;
        character.position = CGPointMake(charPos, charPos1);
        character.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(xSpeed, 15);
    }
}

Comment: I just looked through your code.  You are both changing the position and adding a speed to your character which will conflict.
Work with speed instead of manually moving the position.  Basically when you touch the rArrow, make the velocity positive in the x-direction.  When your touch releases in the touchesEnded then set the velocity to 0.

Comment: Do you understand how the physics world in spritekit works?  Just trying to figure out how in depth to go about this.

Comment: Yes thank you! i will try this and hopefully i get it to work :)